# Working with private methods in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've two private methods in my event.rb model an I want these two methods should invoke on two different actions in my events controller.

event.rb

```
    private 

  def create_notification_on_accept
    self.notifications.create(action_type: "Accept", actor_id: participant.id,
    user_id: user_id)
 end

 def create_notification_on_reject
  self.notifications.create(action_type: "Reject", actor_id: participant.id,
  user_id: user_id)
end
```

events_controller.rb

```
  def accept_invitation
   @participants.where(user_id: current_user.id).update_all(is_attending: true)
   render "update"
 end

def reject_invitation
 @participants.where(user_id: current_user.id).update_all(is_attending: false)
 render "update"
end
```

How can I call these two private mathods in my controller.?

Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Why don't you make them public?

Comment: "Methods that are private can only be called by methods within the same class or within the same module". That's the basic definition of private method.

Comment: Santosh, If I make them public can I access them directly from the controller actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make them class methods to call them in your controllers.

```
 private 

 def self.create_notification_on_accept(event)
   # I don't know where are you getting participant id, so pass it if you need
   # additionally, if they are available on event object then you could do
   # event.participant.id, event.user_id since the background of the code is not given
   # hence I'm making some assumptions 
   event.notifications.create(action_type: "Accept", actor_id: participant.id,
   user_id: user_id)
 end

 def self.create_notification_on_reject(event)
   event.notifications.create(action_type: "Reject", actor_id: participant.id,
 user_id: user_id)
 end
```

And in your controller you can do this

```
def accept_invitation
   #find event so you can pass it as a param
   Event.create_notification_on_accept(event)
   @participants.where(user_id: current_user.id).update_all(is_attending: true)
   render "update"
end
```

However, a better thing to do this would be to have callbacks instead of class methods. That way you can reduce the overhead of calling the method everywhere, instead you can leave it onto the model to know when to call.

Comment: Using callabacks is easy part of doing it. Unfortunately, we can not create a callbacks for  create_invitation and reject_invitation, since these are not rails default callbacks.



When I call them with Event.metod_name as you said it gives me error.


Error Log

NoMethodError (undefined method `create_notification_on_create' for #<Class:0x00000008c62a48>):
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:47:in `accept_invitation'

Comment: Well it has got nothing do about calling it.  Do you see the line self.notification.create that's expecting an object of the class event. That's why ur getting the error. You can pass the event object to the method and use that instead of self and it should work just fine. Sorry I'm on mobile so can't post any code. But I'm sure that's what is causing the problem.

Comment: I changed my code as you said. Unfortunately it is not working. May be I could be here with my code. Please check this and help me where am doing wrong.
http://pastebin.com/PVd21r30

Thank you

Comment: It perfectly worked(Updated answer). Although, am not sure why should I pass event in the controller. It worked very well. Thanks for your help. Accepting your answer, right away!.

Answer (score 1):

There are no private methods in ruby (as we all know as in Java), you can call them with the Object#send method.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-send

Answer (score 0):

You can not call private methods, there is no way for it directly. You could create wrappers that are those methods but as public. Best solution move them to public segemnt

Comment: If I make them public can I then call those two methods in the controller actions directly ?

Comment: You can call them on object of that class. If you got `event` object in controller 'Yes', can not call them without `event` object.

Comment: @Prabhakar, you can call them just like that. You either have to call them on objects or use class methods and call them on their class like I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to get these methods to fire when your particular controller actions are fired.

1. Make them callbacks, these could fire when you save the event. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html
2. Put the methods in a service layer object, which updates the participants, and creates the notifications. In this case your controller methods could create a new Reply instance. The Reply class could then have methods to update_participants, and create_notification

In general if you want to call, or test private methods, then think of this as an indicator that these methods want to be public methods, probably in another class.